# xCrud : Search Bar

Tags: php, crud

I'm currently using and experimenting with xCrud. I'm now wondering, since there is no documentation about those features, if it would be easily possible to have multiple search bars where you can search for different things.

Right now my xCrud file looks like that

```
<?php

$xcrud->table('table1');
$xcrud->join('ID','table2','ID');

echo $xcrud->render();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this feature for search different things:

```
$xcrud->search_columns('productVendor,quantityInStock,buyPrice','quantityInStock');
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the xcrud search bar allows you to search all columns in your rendered table. It also allows you to select specific fields to search. The `$xcrud->search_columns()` function mentioned by @eneskomur is useful when you are displaying data using `$xcrud->subselect()`.